# How to add a hyperlink to text with SkiaSharp

Tags: text, hyperlink, skiasharp

I have SkiaSharp package installed in a .NET 6 project. I have an image that I use as a template and send it by email, and I dynamically write text on it.

**How can I add a hyperlink to a text? How can I solve it?**

I tried to create an invisible rectangle over the text I want to add the hyperlink and generate an event that when I press it redirects me to google but it didn't work because the SkiaSharp library doesn't have this function since I'm not using SkiaSharp Xamarin or Forms. I am using the common SkiaSharp library.

Comment: you are using maui? in what context you want to capture gestures?